# How can I transfer Thunderbird profile from Windows XP?

Tags: windows, thunderbird

I've saved the profile on a flash drive by using the Import/Export feature of the Windows Thunderbird. However, the Thunderbird in Ubuntu seems to be a reduced version of the Windows one.

In the Import wizard under the prompt: "please select the type of file to import" it is not possible to enter anything, so I cannot direct the wizard to the saved profile (exported from the laptop).

Also, I don't want to do a profile replacement, as I've got some emails in the Thunderbird on Ubuntu and wouldn't like them to be overwritten. Please note the desktop Thunderbird is set to IMAP, whereas the laptop Thunderbird contains old emails and is not connected to the server.

Comment: I'm just installing Thunderbird now to see if I can help.

Comment: Hmm I see the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy your windows thunderbird profile inside your `~/.mozilla/thunderbird` (or may be it is `~/.config/thunderbird`) directory. You may either rename it as default, or select it from the commandline `thunderbird -P`.

Note: Some paths might be screwed up because of path differences in windows and linux. You can either fix them in the files manually, or reset them from the UI. I have not used thunderbird since long to help you more. Someone else might give you a more concrete answer.